# CodeIgniter Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am using bootstrap multiselect plugin to create comboboxes with checkboxes inside. I want to populate the second combobox related to the value of the first combobox from database. I tried the codes in google but it's not working. Here is the controller:

```
public function getFabricSupplier()
{
    $item = $this->input->post('item');
    $data['supplier'] = $this->ModelDB->get_FabricSupplier($item);

    foreach($data['supplier'] as $val)
    {
        echo "<option value=".$val['Name'].">".$val['Name']."</option>";
    }
}
```

And here is my jquery:

```
$('#cmbFabric1').multiselect({
onChange: function(option, checked)
{
    var item = $(option).val();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '/mps/index.php/mps/getFabricSupplier',
        data: {item:item},
        success: function(response)
        {
            $('#cmbSupplier1').empty();
            $('#cmbSupplier').append(response);
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: your question is not clear.
can you provide an example output

Comment: No output is generated... I want to change the value of second dropdown by the value of the first dropdown.

Comment: are there any console errors?

Comment: none also... I tried the other examples in other websites but none is working...

Comment: Please mention you error?

Comment: As I mentioned from my previous comments there's no console error and there's no output were generated also.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to create a test route to call that controller/action so that you could test the result of it. Without having to POST something.

After the foreach, with all the echo's i would put a return true. (i don't know if it's required for some reason)

Make sure this call:

```
$data['supplier'] = $this->ModelDB->get_FabricSupplier($item);
```

Returns already some kind of array object. If it's a query result use:

```
foreach($data['supplier']->result_array() as $val)
```